# Derive layout param width from textView text length

Tags: android, textview

I want to set the width of a textView programmatically.  I want the width to vary with the length of the text (value) of the textView. The text of the textView must not wrap.   If the text of a textView is "OLA OMO ALARE", how can I use the length of this string (13) to derive the correct value to set         lp.width to, in the code below ?

```
    LayoutParams lp = tv.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

I tried the code below, but the width was not long enough, thus text was auto wrapped in textView.

```
lp.width =  Math.round(  tv.getPaint().measureText(tv.getText().toString())) )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you dont want it to WRAP ? It is very straight forward..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to use Rect instance for this.

2) Then you need to use this in textView's `getPaint()` and `getTextBound()` methods which allows you to put your text of the textview.

3) At the end just get width from the Rect instance.

Code is here with all the steps implemented, 
I tested this and it works fine. Hope it helps.

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("AALAP");
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), rect);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: width: "+rect.width());
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I followed your recommendation, but the derived width was not long enough, thus the text was auto wrapped in textview.  My code:
        statusCodeTitle.setText("Status Code_loplop:");
        statusCodeTitle.getPaint().getTextBounds(statusCodeTitle.getText().toString(), 0, statusCodeTitle.getText().length(), rect);
        titleMaxWidth = rect.width();

      rect.width() returned 189
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` constant for this.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myTextView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
myTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```